# Azure AAD Proxy with RDS webclient RDP issue

Tags: azure, proxy, rdp, rds, rdweb

I have currently implemented the below solution into our environment so that we can achieve pre-authorisation to access our RDWeb / HTML5 WebClient:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-integrate-with-remote-desktop-services#support-for-other-client-configurations

Whilst I can successfully log in and access published applications and the remote desktop within the browser itself fine, when I download the actual RDP file I get the following error when running it:

> Your computer can't connect to the remote computer because authentication to the firewall failed due to missing firewall credentials. To resolve the issue, go to the firewall website that your network administrator recommends, and then try the connection again, or contact your network administrator for assitance.

I would be happy for users to use the browser, however they need Multi-monitor support and the browser version unfortunately does not have Multi-Monitor support.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still...
This is unfortunately not possible with Pre Authentication.

The following options exist:

- Use AAD Proxy without Pre-Auth
- Use RDWeb in Edge IE mode (i know...) - this is required because it uses an ActiveX plugin to use the Pre Authentication.

I found this solution to be severly lacking unfortunately :(